# Generic Method Signature for DAL Update method

Tags: c#, generics, data-access-layer

I am working with a multi-purpose Stored Procedure that does either an insert or update for either Claim or Policy. I would like to only create one DAL method to call this update/insert.

I have a IBaseAdjustment that contains all of the properties of both a Claim Object and a Policy Object. Claim is a subset of Policy so It will inherit Policy. The stored procedure is set up to default to values if none are passed in so therefore I am using nullable properties where possible.

I am stuck on the method signature for the Update call. I have

```
    public bool UpdateManualAdjustmentTransaction<T>() where T : IBaseAdjustment
    {}
```

I am just not sure how to set the reference to my entity now to set the parameters I would have thought it would be something like

```
IbaseAdjustment _adjustment = T as IBaseAdjustment;
```

but it does not like that. Suggestions?
'Thanks

Comment: I think I got it         public bool UpdateManualAdjustmentTransaction(IBaseAdjustment adjustment) 
        {}?

Comment: You should deal with T as a type.. T as IBaseAdjustment simply doesn't make sense. It is not clear to me what you would like to do with adjustment in that function. And where that adjustment is coming from. Maybe you meant having something like public bool Update<T>(T adj) where T:IBaseAdjustment, then you can use adj as it was an IBaseAdjustment. But maybe you don't need generics.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just going to use the interface, there is no need for this to be a generic method at all:

```
public bool UpdateManualAdjustmentTransaction(IBaseAdjustment baseAdjustment)
{
     // use baseAdjustment
}
```

This will let you pass either of your entities to this method directly.

Comment: That was what I came up with about 2 seconds after I posted the question and then read it back. I think I need a break ;) Thanks